# Add a block to a page with event observer

Tags: magento-1, event-observer, blocks, static-block

I'm trying to add a static block to a page with an observer.
The event that I'm listening to is `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` and this is my observer code:

```
<?php
...
class Antonino_Banner_Model_Observer
{
    public function showBannerWhenLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    {
        $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
        $pageId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $selectedCatId = Mage::getStoreConfig('antoninobanner/general/choose_category');

       if ($pageId==$selectedCatId){
           Mage::log('Bingo! PageId= '. $pageId.' SelectedId= '.$selectedCatId);
           $messageBlock = $layout->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('antonino_banner');
           $breadcrumbs = $layout->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
           $breadcrumbs->append($messageBlock);
       }/*else{
           Mage::log('Oh no! The ids do not match');
       }*/
    }
}
```

The event is regularly triggered and in the system.log I can read the "Bingo!..." string.
But on the page, the 'antonino_banner' block is not added.
Naturally, I've created a static block in **admin->static blocks**.

Any help will be appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: Make sure `breadcrumbs` block is there on the page as you are appending your block to it

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Yes, the `breadcrumbs` block is on the page because if I write `var_dump(Mage::app()->getLayout())`, when I reload the page, in the `protected '_blocks'` array there is the following element 
`'breadcrumbs' => 
        object(Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs)[199]`

Answer (score 0):

I think that your are not using a good event, it's a little late and the layout is already **rendered**, try to use these :

- `controller_action_layout_load_before`
- `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before`

**Edit:**

Try this one: `core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before`

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32324/how-to-check-whether-a-block-exist-based-on-its-type)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly both the events that you suggested appen too soon: the blocks are not still loaded.
In fact I get this error: `Call to a member function append() on boolean `. I think this means that magento still doesn't know the name of the blocks.

Comment: Or, he don't find a breadcrumbs block, please try the footer `$layout->getBlock('footer')`, try also this event `core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before`

Comment: With those changes I've got the following error: `Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think could handle this, but I'm not very satisfied by the result.
I'm listening to

> core_block_abstract_to_html_after

And my Observer code is:

```
<?php    

class Antonino_Banner_Model_Observer
{
    public function showBannerWhenLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $pageId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $selectedCatId = Mage::getStoreConfig('antoninobanner/general/choose_category');

       if ($pageId==$selectedCatId){
           $block = $observer->getBlock();
           if($block->getNameInLayout() == 'breadcrumbs')
           {
               $transport = $observer->getTransport();
               $html = $transport->getHtml();
               $html .= '<h1>We need to append something here</h1>';
               $transport->setHtml($html);
           }
       }/*else{
           Mage::log('Oh no! The ids do not match');
       }*/
    }
}
```

I don't like this solution very much because this means I must write some raw HTML code directly in this page...